# What does :: mean in Rust?

Tags: syntax, rust

What does the `::` syntax in Rust, as seen [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/src/collections/home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/dist2-linux/build/src/libcollections/trie.rs.html#428-428), mean:

```
fn chunk(n: uint, idx: uint) -> uint {
    let sh = uint::BITS - (SHIFT * (idx + 1));
    (n >> sh) & MASK
}
```

In languages like Haskell it means a type hint, but here the compiler already has an annotation of that values type, so it seems it's likely type casting.

Comment: Is it not the class identifer? See lines 13-19

Comment: Beware! You are linking to **very old versions of Rust**. You should ensure that everything you read says Rust 1.0 beta or above!

Comment: Yeah, looks like the trie implementation just got dropped since then, which is why I couldn't find a newer version.

Comment: There are [crates that advertise](https://crates.io/search?q=trie) that they implement tries.

Comment: Related: [What does :: (double colon) mean before an identifier?](/q/65955573/2189130)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Please review [Appendix B: Operators and Symbols](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) of *The Rust Programming Language*.

---

In this case, the double colon (`::`) is the path separator. [Paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html) are comprised of *crates*, *modules*, and *items*.

The full path for [your example item, updated for 1.0](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#associatedconstant.BITS) is:

```
std::usize::BITS
```

Here, `std` is the crate, `usize` is a module, and `BITS` is the specific item — in this case a constant.

If you scroll up in your file, you'll see `use core::usize`. `use` adds the path to the set of items to look in. That's how you can get away with just saying `usize::BITS`. The `core` crate is an [implementation detail of the façade that is the `std` crate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951024/stdopsadd-or-coreopsadd), so you can just substitute `std` for `core` in normal code.

---

`::` can also be used as a way to specify generic types when they cannot otherwise be inferred; this is called the [*turbofish*](https://turbo.fish/).

See also:

- [What is the syntax: `instance.method::<SomeThing>()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52360464/155423)

Comment: The 1-st example [here, documentation for `set` metod of `rlua::Table`](https://docs.rs/rlua/0.9.5/rlua/struct.Table.html) don't seem to be covered by this definition. They create there a variable `lua`, and then do `lua.exec::<()>(r#"…"#, None)`. The `::` doesn't look like a path as in your example.

Comment: I asked on IRC: turns out, the `::<Type>` syntax is used to supply the `Type` parameter. That's like C++/C#/Java templates, except for some reason there's a redundant double colon.

Comment: are these two uses of `::` (path separator & turbofish) related in some way?

Comment: That turbofish site is cute... :P

Answer (score 3):

Oops. I wasn't reading very clearly. In this case, it's just the normal way of referring to anything under a module. `uint::BITS` is a constant, it seems.