# std::ops::Add or core::ops::Add?

Tags: rust, standard-library

These two traits ([std::ops::Add](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html), [core::ops::Add](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/trait.Add.html)) provide the same functionality, and they both use the same example (both utilize `std::ops::Add`). Their set of implementors differ somewhat.

Should one default to using `std::ops::Add`? Why do both, as opposed to one, of them exist?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There aren't two traits. There is one trait which is exported under several interchangeable names. *This is far from unique*. Virtually everything in `core` is also exported from `std`, and virtually always under exactly the same path (i.e., you can just replace the "core" prefix with "std").

As for which one you should use: If you have a reason to not link to the standard library (`#![no_std]`), then the `std::*` one isn't available so obviously you use `core::*`. If on the other hand you *do* use the standard library, you should use the `std::*` re-export. It is more customary and requires less typing.

Comment: What if I'm creating a library that doesn't need to use `std` stuff. Should I always mark it as `#![no_std]` in order for other no-std-crates to use it? What if I don't mark it `#![no_std]` and use `std::ops::Add`: can other no-std-crates use my crate?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt The conventions about this are still unclear. You can't use a `std` crate from `no_std` even if it happens to use the subset of `std` that is also in `core`, which would be a reason to apply it liberally. But if a `no_std` crate later finds a reason to start depending on `std`, this would be a breaking change, so some people are wary of being too `no_std`-happy.

Answer (score 27):

They're in fact exactly the same, despite the set of implementors being listed as slightly different.

The `core` library is designed for bare-metal/low-level tasks, and is thus more barebones than what `std` can provide by assuming an operating system exists. However, people using `std` will want the stuff that's in `core` too (e.g. `Add` or `Option` or whatever), and so to avoid having to load both `std` and `core`, `std` reexports everything from `core`, [via `pub use`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5807fbbfde3ad04820f6fa0269711c81538057ec/src/libstd/lib.rs#L332-L333). That is, `std` provides aliases/import paths for the things in `core`.

There are [some unfortunate error messages](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21934) where the compiler points to the original source of an item, not the reexport, which might not be in a crate you're `extern crate`ing.