# What is the syntax: `instance.method::<SomeThing>()`?

Tags: rust, syntax

I read the below syntax from [byteorder](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.2.6/byteorder/):

```
rdr.read_u16::<BigEndian>()
```

I can't find any documentation which explains the syntax `instance.method::<SomeThing>()`

Comment: check https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/generics.html#resolving-ambiguities and https://matematikaadit.github.io/posts/rust-turbofish.html

Comment: The most important link regarding this syntax: https://turbo.fish/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This construct is called turbofish. If you search for this statement, you will discover its definition and its usage.

Although the first edition of *The Rust Programming Language* is outdated, I feel that [this particular section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.27.0/book/first-edition/generics.html) is better than in the [second book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/second-edition/appendix-02-operators.html#non-operator-symbols).

Quoting the second edition:

> `path::<...>`, `method::<...>`
> Specifies parameters to generic type, function, or method in an expression; often referred to as turbofish (e.g., `"42".parse::<i32>()`)

You can use it in any kind of situation where the compiler is not able to deduce the type parameter, e.g.

```
fn main () {
    let a = (0..255).sum();
    let b = (0..255).sum::<u32>();
    let c: u32 = (0..255).sum();
}
```

`a` does not work because it cannot deduce the variable type.
`b` does work because we specify the type parameter directly with the turbofish syntax.
`c` does work because we specify the type of `c` directly.

Comment: The reason that `::` is required in expressions is that it avoids a syntax ambiguity with the less-than and greater-than operators. This is different from types, where you write `Vec<i32>` and not `Vec::<i32>` (less-than and greater-than don't exist in the syntax for types).

Comment: There's been several attempts to resolve the syntax ambiguity that starblue mentioned (and [some are still ongoing](https://github.com/varkor/rfcs/pull/1)), so it's possible you might be able to leave the `::` out some day. It's a [trickier problem](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/53562) than it might seem at first glance, though :)

Comment: I prefere `c` because it's shorter

Comment: Neither `b` nor `c` are inherently better than the other. Each have times that they are useful and more succinct. Both are equally idiomatic.