# How to call an associated function on a generic type?

Tags: rust, traits

I have 2 trait implementations in a file. How can I call the `first_function` from the second implementation of `Trait`?

```
impl<T: Trait> Module<T> {
    pub fn first_function() {
        // some code here
    }
}

impl<T: Trait> Second<T::SomeType> for Module<T> {
    pub fn second_function() {
        // Needs to call the first function available in first trait implementation.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: *from the second implementation of `Trait`* — There's only **one** implementation of `Trait` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use turbofish (`::<>`) syntax:

```
Module::<T>::first_function()
```

complete example:

```
struct Module<T> {
    i: T,
}

trait Trait {
    type SomeType;
}

trait Second<T> {
    fn second_function();
}

impl<T: Trait> Module<T> {
    fn first_function() {
        // some code here
    }
}

impl<T: Trait> Second<T::SomeType> for Module<T> {
    fn second_function() {
        Module::<T>::first_function();
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1b71fafd22a92d914267d981dddb0ec)

Also see this related question about the turbofish syntax:

- [What is the syntax: `instance.method::<SomeThing>()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360464/what-is-the-syntax-instance-methodsomething)

Comment: @WeslyWiser Please feel free to rollback my change if you feel that it goes against your actual answer. I just wanted to provide additional resources regatrdint the turbofish syntax