# Is it possible to deserialize part of a JSON object with serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

Assume following JSON:

```js
{
  "person": {
    "first_name": "Ala",
    "last_name": "Makota"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize this object to a struct like following, skipping `"person"`?

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Person {
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
}
```

It's easy to deserialize the JSON object to a wrapped struct, like this:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Object {
  person: Person
}
```

but in my case, I'm only interested in `Person` structure.

*EDIT:*

While I'm aware that I could use `serde_json`'s `Value` type to operate on JSON almost as on a `Map`, I'm specifically interested in the possibility of leveraging  `derive` and maybe attributes to achieve my goal.

Comment: It looks like you can solve it by using https://docs.rs/json/0.12.1/json/

Comment: @MaxV Seems to me that I could achieve something similar by using `serde_json`'s `Value` type. While this is something I may end up using, please see the edit of my question.

Answer (score 4):

Thinking the json as a map with a "person" key and a `Person` value it is possible to deserialize into an `HashMap`
and then retrive the `Person` value.

```
let person = r#"
{
    "person": {
      "first_name": "Ala",
      "last_name": "Makota"
    }
  }
"#;

let deserialized = serde_json::from_str::<HashMap<&str, Person>>(&person);
```

The [turbo fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360464/what-is-the-syntax-instance-methodsomething/52361559) `::<HashMap<&str, Person>>` is used as a compact way to help the compiler to determine the type of deserialization.